# How do I find the correct path, Node.js + html

Tags: html, node.js, directory, hosting

this might be silly but this code is not finding the correct folder to display my images from, and i dont know why:

```
fetch(`/gallery/${galleryName}`)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            galleryDiv.innerHTML = html;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching gallery:', error);
        });
});
```

that section of code above is located in my /public/js folder

it's used by my app.js in the root directory

```
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

// i chaned the line below from gallery/:name to /public/gallery/:name, still doesnt work
app.get('/public/gallery/:name', (req, res) => {
    const galleryName = req.params.name;
    const galleryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'gallery', galleryName);

    fs.readdir(galleryPath, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error reading directory:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error: Unable to read gallery directory');
            return;
        }

        const imagesHTML = files
            .filter(file => file.endsWith('.jpg') || file.endsWith('.jpeg') || file.endsWith('.png') || file.endsWith('.gif'))
            .map(file => `<img src="/images/${galleryName}/${file}" alt="${file}" width="150" height="150">`)
            .join('');

        const galleryHTML = `<div>${imagesHTML}</div>`;
        res.send(galleryHTML);
    });
});
```

this code worked before I uploaded it to my hosting service, i get this error when i look at inspect element
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYE3q.png)
that line is

```
fetch(`/gallery/${galleryName}`)
```

to access the folders for each webpage its,
root>public>gallery>all the gallery folders (i.e f_icon_etc)

in the app.js ive
// i chaned the line below from gallery/:name to /public/gallery/:name, still doesnt work

the previous name for the gallery directory was "images", but after trying to get it to work i changed it to "gallery" but that didnt work either